# Javascript extension built-in classes

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I found an example of the expansion of the built-in javascript

```
var n = 3;
Number.prototype.times = function(f, context) {
                var n = Number(this); 
                for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    f.call(context, i);
                }
            };
n.times(function(n) {
    console.log(n);
});
```

I understand that I call the function *f* (console.log) through the object *context*.

I understand that we pass this function a serial number from 0 to *n*.

The method *time* accepts only one argument - function console.log
Question: Where in the code appeared object *context*?

Thank you all

Comment: "The method time accepts only one argument" nope, it accepts two. It just might be undefined. Reference: [`.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

Comment: From what you posted, you can't know. `context` is something the user of `Number.prototype.times` could provide if he/she chooses to.

Comment: Yes, the method can take two time arguments, but in this case it is only passed one argument

Comment: OK, I understand, we can pass to the method call NULL instead of an object

Comment: Now all is clear, it was a difficult example to understand so much clearer.

var n = 3; Number.prototype.times = function(f) { var n = Number(this); for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)  f(i);};

Answer (score 0):

A function allows any number of parameters to be supplied. If there's too many, they're not used and if there's too few, the ones that are left out are `undefined`. `n.times(myFunction)` is the same as `n.times(myFunction, undefined)`, but just shorter to write.

The `context` is actually not correctly named, `scope` would be better. When omitted, the global scope is used. The following is the same:

`n.times(myFunction.bind(scope));`
`n.times(myFunction, scope);`

More about scopes and binding:http://www.reactive.io/tips/2009/04/28/binding-scope-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Now all is clear, it was a difficult example.
To understand so much clearer:

```
var n = 3;
Number.prototype.times = function(f) {
    var n = Number(this);
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) f(i);
};
```